# No Auth "Authentication required" Error in redis Mass Insertion?

Tags: python, redis, redis-py

I am trying to insert millios of rows to redis .
I gone through the redis massinsertion tutorials and tried

**cat data.txt | python redis_proto.py | redis-cli -p 6321 -a "myPassword" --pipe**

here the redis_proto.py is the python script which reads the data.txt and convert to redis protocol.

I got some error like as below

**All data transferred. Waiting for the last reply...
NOAUTH Authentication required.
NOAUTH Authentication required.**

any help or suggestions would be appreciated ?

Comment: Can you paste your script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess in your password there will be "$". If it is remove that It will work.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can add password in the connectionpool parameters like this :

```
pool=redis.ConnectionPool(host=redis_host,port=int(redis_port),db=int(redis_db),password=redis_pass)
```